# How to get the assignment title from Google Classroom with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-classroom

I want to get the assignment title of each assignment posted by the teacher in a specific course in Google Classroom. Can someone help me with this? When I try the API explorer on the official website, it returns the correct result but it doesn't work with my python file.

```
    service = build('classroom', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Classroom API
    results = service.courses().courseWork().get(courseId).execute()
    courses = results.get('courses')

    if not courses:
        print('No courses found.')
    else:
        print('Courses:')
        for course in courses:
            print(course)
```

Comment: I guess you meant using `list` instead of `get`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you already accepted an answer, I think other people with your same problem might not be able to solved their issue based on that. Therefore, I'm posting an answer too.

#### Use correct parameters for "get" method:

You didn't specify which specific problem you had / what error were you getting (you just said `it doesn't work`), but the code you shared is not correct:

If you want to use [courses.courseWork.get](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/get), you have to provide at least two parameters, for `courseId` and for `id` (referred to the assignment id), so it should be like this:

```
service.courses().courseWork().get(courseId=courseId, id=courseWorkId).execute()
```

#### Use "list" instead of "get":

But since you want to get the assignment titles of all the assignments in the course (and not for a single assignment), you should be using [courses.courseWork.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/list) instead. Your code should be something like this (where `title` is the title of each assignment):

```
courseWorkList = service.courses().courseWork().list(courseId=courseId).execute()
for courseWork in courseWorkList["courseWork"]:
    title = courseWork["title"]
    print(title)
```

And if the number of assignments is very large, you might need to use `pageToken` and [nextPageToken](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/list#body.ListCourseWorkResponse.FIELDS.next_page_token), and call this method in a loop.

#### Use appropriate scopes:

If you're using `list`, you need to specify any of [these scopes](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/list#authorization-scopes). Otherwise, you are not authorized to access this resource:

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students.readonly
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me.readonly
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.me

#### Reference:

- [get(courseId=None, id=*, x__xgafv=None)](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/classroom/v1/python/latest/classroom_v1.courses.courseWork.html#get)
- [list(courseId=None, orderBy=None, pageSize=None, courseWorkStates=None, pageToken=None, x__xgafv=None)](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/classroom/v1/python/latest/classroom_v1.courses.courseWork.html#list)

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the coursework, you have to edit the predefined `SCOPE` in the sample code provided (and also delete the token.pickle file).
Check [this](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/list), for a better understanding.